# Display Div + span on same line?

Tags: html, css

Having trouble displaying a div and a span on the same line.. their styles are..

**DIV**

```
 color: black;
 display: inline;
 font-family: arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 height: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 overflow-y: visible;
 padding-top: 0px;
 white-space: nowrap;
 width: 0px;
```

**SPAN**

```
color: black;
display: inline;
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
height: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
overflow-y: visible;
padding-top: 0px;
width: 0px;
```

**DIV WHICH BOTH ARE WRAPPED IN**

```
color: black;
display: block;
float: left;
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
height: 20px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 8px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
overflow-y: visible;
padding-top: 1px;
width: 373px;
```

What would I need to change to get the div and span displaying on the same line? currently the div displays and then the span on the line under it.

Comment: Just curious why you don't use a span rather than a div if you want it to be inline anyway? This is the default behavior of a span so it seems that would be best suited. Do you not have control over the HTML perhaps? Oh, and you can simpy use `margin: 0;` or `margin: 0 0 0 8px;` rather than specifying each margin separately (top, bottom, etc.)

Comment: which browser are you using ? Cant reproduce the issue on ff , ie8 .  [http://jsfiddle.net/WJjZs/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/WJjZs/1/)

Answer (score 11):

You need to add `display:inline;`

Comment: Did he edit the question, because the second line of the div styles is `display: inline;`

Answer (score 1):

The default 'display' value for a Div is to be a block level element, like a paragraph, that covers the whole 'line'.

You need to set the Div to be 'display: inline' to appear next to the span element.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashburlaczenko/fxt42/).

You are missing floats an position in your css.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer without the HTML. At a first glance, I'd say you should float them both left.

Answer (score 0):

I think float:left on div should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

In the wrapping div you should have:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

and remove the display property from both elements.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-block`; to your first div.